# Best way to increase hospital value?

Tags: two-point-hospital

I forgot the name of it but I'm on the location where you first gain access to the Marketing room. One of the requirements to get 3 stars is to raise the hospital value to $5M. When I got to the point where the other two requirements were checked off, my value was at about $2.5M. I have purchased all the plots and I have more or less used every single space I can to put more rooms. When you hover over the $5M value requirement it says that to raise hospital value, earn more money, expand your hospital and increase profits. Since this is the last thing I need to do to get 3 stars, I've been 100% focusing on increasing the value. I first tried increasing the attractiveness by placing gold star awards EVERYWHERE I could. Then I tried focusing on hiring only 4- and 5-star staff, but this made no difference and seemed to make things worse. By this point I was hovering around $3.5M value. Then I thought I would try and hire 0-star staff to train them up to 5-star but again, no discernible difference. Then I thought to try making every office level 5 but again, no big difference. I tried playing with the pricing, making it -20% and -30%, and then up to +20% but that didn't seem to change anything major. During all of this I am also constantly running research projects and LARGE marketing campaigns. It's hard to tell what has the most effect because the value indicator doesn't change instantly, it's more of a month-to-month change.

I am currently around $4.1M value so I'm almost there but I'm out of ideas. I need to drastically improve profits but I can't really expand the hospital anymore, maybe 2 or 3 more rooms. Has anybody figured out the fastest way to raise hospital value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So long as you are making money the hospital value will increase over time as your stored money increases. Training etc does have an impact because it increases your overall profits, but the impact is only noticeable over time. Basically, stop spending money and wait.

Comment: I did a bunch of reading about Flemington (the level I'm referring to here) on the TPH Subreddit and that was the basic consensus. I got 3 stars last night by setting my prices to +100% and sitting back. After about 10 minutes I hit 3 star!